# Charts animations not working with PrimeNG

Tags: chart.js, primeng

I an using PrimeNG 15.2.0 and chart.js 4.0.1 and trying to get animations for charts to work.
I copied the data and the config from here ([https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#looping-tension-[property]](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#looping-tension-%5Bproperty%5D)) so it looks like this

```
this.dataTest = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Try hiding me',
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 26, 55, 40],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
  }]
}

this.optionsTest = {
  type: 'line',
  data: this.dataTest,
  options: {
    animations: {
      tension: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        from: 1,
        to: 0,
        loop: true
      }
    },
  }
}
```

The chart is defined in HTML like this

```
<p-chart type="line" [data]="dataTest" [options]="optionsTest"></p-chart>
```

The chart shows up just fine on my page, but there is no animation happening. Its the same with the other example from the chart.js page mentioned earlier. The only animation I see is the default animation when showing/hiding the graph where it moves away upwards when hiding the graph and comes back down when showing it again.

Do chartjs animations just not work in primeNG or what is the problem here?